# Change single value using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have records that look like:

```
GCR,
ER, 
SR,
WR,
NER
CR
```

I want to change the GCR to GC using a case statement on my view while also showing the other values. How can I do it?

Comment: `CASE value WHEN 'GCR' THEN 'GC' ELSE value END`.

Comment: CASE WHEN FieldName = 'GCR' THEN 'GC' ELSE FieldName END ?

Comment: what you tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below query :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'GCR' THEN 'CR' ELSE ColumnName END 
FROM your_table
```

Comment: @RichBenner,I updated my post for showing other values also.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

select case when YourColumnName= 'a123' then 'CR' end 'ColumnName' from YourTableName

Answer (score 0):

You use `case` with `else`:

```
select (case when col = 'GCR' then 'CR' else col end) as new_col
```

If you need to do this repeatedly, you can add a computed column with the expression:

```
alter t add new_col as (case when col = 'GCR' then 'CR' else col end);
```

Then, any query can use `new_col` and it would be calculated correctly (on the fly).